# How many stars were on Ox King's / Chi Chi's Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball

In the Dragon Ball series, Goku's Dragon Ball had 4 stars.
How many stars were on Ox King's / Chi Chi's Dragon Ball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goku and Bulma got the seven star dragon ball from the Ox king's castle. The Ox king agreed to give them the dragonball if they put out the fire that was destroying his castle. Once the fire was put out by Master Roshi, Bulma then used the dragon radar to locate the dragon ball in the ruins of the castle.

[image: bulma finds the 7 star dragon ball]

This picture is from the Dragonball manga. It was from chapter 15 on page 9.